# Request animation frame returning a result?

Tags: javascript

I have this idea in my head but am wondering how it is done, or if it is even possible.

I have a request animation frame like this:

```
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback,  element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
```

What i want to do is when it calls a function and the animation ends... i want it to stop calling some how.

So this would be the pseudo logic to my idea:

```
do{
var result = requestAnimFrame( my_function.bind(null,start) );
}while(result == true);
//rest of code should not run until animation is finished
```

Is this possible at all ?  If so how would i alter my function to support a return ?

EDIT
This is my animation function....

```
function my_function(start){

var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
var into_anim = now - start;

    amount = 0.5000;
    opacity = amount * (into_anim - 10);
    opacity = parseFloat(opacity.toFixed(5))
    if(opacity > 1){ opacity = 1; }

if(opacity != 1){
    requestAnimFrame(my_function.bind(null,start));
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your animation function look like? It would call `requestAnimationFrame` with itself as long as the animation goes on, and when the animation ends you just don't call it anymore - and the whole process stops.

Comment: @pimvdb give me a moment i will add it to my question :)

Comment: The only thing I see is that you should do `.bind(null, start)` - the first argument is the `this` value, all subsequent arguments are arguments being bound. Other than that the idea of calling RAF seems very correct.

Comment: But do i need a Do while loop ? Or will code after the animation call not run until after my animation has stopped being called?

Comment: If you call `my_function()`, then it takes care of calling RAF itself until it shouldn't anymore. You've implemented that correctly with the `if`. I'm not sure what's not working here.

Comment: Does my initial call to my_function not require animation frame request?

Comment: The first call is only about the first frame. Its effect on the animation as a whole is negligible. It's about all other frames, which *are* called with RAF here already, which is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `requestAnimationFrame` is asynchronous as like as `setTimeout`. So, you will need to call it "recursively" from and with your `my_function` - ending it by *not* making another call when the condition is met.

If you want to execute something after the animation, use a callback which gets invoked once the condition is met. Note that your function returns immidiately, they will only time functions (itself and the callback) to be executed somewhen in the future.

```
function my_function(callback) {
    var start = Date.now();
    frame(); // begin first frame
    function frame() {
        var into_anim = Date.now() - start;
        var opacity = 0.5 * (into_anim - 10);

        if(opacity > 1) {
            opacity = 1;
            callback(); // this was the last frame, do the next thing
        } else
            requestAnimFrame(frame);
     }
}
```

call it:

```
my_function(function(){ alert("It's done"); });
alert("It just began");
```

Comment: Question though if i have code "after" my call to my_function will code after it execute only once request animation frame is finished repeating?

Comment: No, rAF does not repeat anything. It just pushes the given function on the future execution queue, and returns immediately. If you want to execute something after your animation, you will need to use a callback. Was that the original question?

Comment: Yeh i don't want code that comes "After" the RAF to execute until it is told to based on a call back to inform it that it is finished animating. (Thats why i thought a "do while" would be the way?) but i don't know how i get it to recieve the call back value with the RAF function in use.

Comment: Yes, its a callback. You might want to read [these](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/35/) [articles](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the requestAnimationFrames return an ID that can be used to stop the animation by calling cancelAnimationFrame(ID) or the browser equivelent in each.

What you might want to do is set up a var that is accessible from your callback function.  Or define something in your callback function to run the cancelAnimationFrame();

maybe something like:

EDIT:

I misunderstood requestAnimationFrame.  It actually requires that you call it every time you're ready for a new frame.  So just not calling it will prevent the animation from continuing.  Updated example below:

```
requestAnimFrame(animCallback);

var postAnimCallback = function(){
     alert('called after animation done');
}    

function animCallback(){
    if(typeof animCallback.count == 'undefined'){
        animCallback.count=0;
    }
    animCallback.count++;
    if(animCallback.count < 300){// or whatever condition you want to check to be sure you are ready for it to animate again.
        requestAnimFrame();
    } else { //since we aren't calling animateframe again, run callback code
        alert('animation done');
        // or run a previously defined animation callback
        postAnimCallback();
    }
}
```

hope that helps!

Comment: If you put alert('test'); after the declaration of rafId would it alert before the animation has even finished or will it wait until RAF is not longer executing.

Comment: It would alert before the animation is finished.  If you want to have a callback that only runs after the animation is done, you would have to put that in your callback method.  I'll update my example.

Comment: Hmm i only want it to parse a variable back to my main script like a return false kind of thing  =/

Comment: The problem is that requestAnimationFrame isn't a blocking function.  It is running things after a period of time as you can see from your inital definition fallback: function( callback,  element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };  It doesn't wait for the animation code to finish for it to continue down your script.  So the only way to run something after its done is through another callback that gets run when the conditions are right.  I actually think @Bergi's example is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you wish to stop the animation after some conditions has been met. To do this the best practice is to use a conditional statement. If the condition has been  met, then call the `requestAnimationFrame` otherwise stop the repaint flow by calling the `cancelRequestAnimationFrame` or `cancelAnimationFrame`, depending on the browser version you are using. For different polyfill we can use the following fallback solution:

```
window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] 
                               || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
```

The basic premise of requestAnimationFrame is that instead of forcing the browser to refresh the browser at a given constant frame rate, even if it's not capable of doing so, we rely on the browser capabilities to manage the refreshing rates, thus get a hook directly into the browser refresh/redraw and on that refresh we can tell the browser to do something specific with requestAnimationFrame.

But back to the original idea, you can accomplish the wished task as the following:

```
(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] 
                               || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 
              timeToCall);
           lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
    };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
    };
}());

var updating = true,
    animationRequest = null;

animationRequest = requestAnimationFrame(function(func) {
    if (updating) {

        // THE DRAWING FUNCTION. WE SKIP THIS SECTION

        animationRequest = requestAnimationFrame(func);
    }
    else {
        updating = false;
        animationRequest = requestAnimationFrame(func);
    }
}));
```

Hope this help!